# Difference between Workflow, Sequential Workflow and State Machine Workflow Templates in Visual Studio 2013 for SharePoint 2013

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, state-machine

What is the difference between Workflow, Sequential Workflow and State Machine Workflow Templates in Visual Studio 2013 for SharePoint 2013? This doesn't seem to be clearly documented. Which one allows code? Which can be used only in On-Premise? Which one can be used only in the Cloud? Can anyone explain in layman's terms, the difference between Sequential and State Machine workflows? I am unable to understand it from the MSDN documentation. Can anyone explain it in simple language with some good examples?